# Superuser credentials not recognized for new Django website and Admin site

Tags: django

I've created a new website using Django 1.8, created a superuser account and logged into the admin interface to initialize some database fields.  I can log continue to log into both the admin site and the actual website, as can a couple hundred users.

I've created a second Django website under a separate project (separate database, settings file, etc.) that contains identical code.  I ran syncdb and created a different superuser account but when I attempt to log into the admin site with my superuser account, it tells me my username or password is incorrect.  I've compared everything with the original website and I can't find anything that's not consistent.

I've confirmed:

- I can log directly into the MySQL database using the database name, database user and password that are contained in the settings file
- I'm referencing the correct settings file from manage.py
- My user record in auth_user has is_staff, is_superuser and is_active all set to 1

I've tried to compare all the configuration files between the two projects and everything matches up as expected.  Does anyone have any suggestions about what could affect the authentication or how I might debug this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of your `runserver` instance? Alternatively, have you tried dropping into a shell with `manage.py shell` and logging in manually? What kind of error do you encounter?

Comment: Please provide more information. Try logging in with shell, and provide with the errors.

Comment: I'm running this on a hosted site under Apache, not using runserver.  I'm not sure exactly what commands to enter into the shell under manage.py to actually log into the admin site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running out of places to look, I deleted and recreated the site database and then reran `manage.py syncdb`. After that, I was able to log into the admin site.  My working theory is that when I entered the superuser password the first time, I pasted into a PUTTY terminal and what it stored for the password was not what I thought it was.

Which kind of doesn't make sense because I did try to add a second superuser using `manage.py createsuperuser` with a really simple password and I still couldn't log in.

Anyway, thanks for the help.